# RadRails Aptana

Tags: radrails

I would like to ask if there is a functionality in RadRails that allows to copy parts of code, save them for further usage and if they are needed justo drop them form palette. It seems to be very useful in my projects as I prepare parts of codes that are selfdescribing and very common in coding. In netbeans I found Palette but I can not find one in RadRails.

Kind Regards,

Lormitto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think the feature you're talking about is creating templates or snippets.

RadRails 2.x has eclipse template support. You can edit them by going to *Preferences > Ruby > Editor > Templates*. Of course, RadRails 2.x is very old now and is deprecated in favor of Studio 3, which has Ruby/Rails support.

Here's the docs on how to create snippets in Studio 3: http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Creating+a+new+snippet